# BFS binary tree that implements Stack in Python

Tags: python, stack, binary-tree, breadth-first-search, tree-traversal

I am looking for implementing BFS (Breadth-First Search) of binary tree in Python using Stack (not Queue!).

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        
    def Empty(self):
        return self.data == []

    def Push(self, x):
        self.data.append(x)

    def Pop(self):
        return self.data.pop()

    def Peek(self):
        return self.data[len(self.data)-1]

    def Size(self):
        return len(self.data)


class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left, right):
        self.data = data
        self.l_node = left
        self.r_node = right


class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root= None

    def bfs_stack(self, node):
        pass


t = Tree()
t.root = Node("1")
t.root.l_node = Node("2")
t.root.l_node.l_node = Node("4")
t.root.l_node.r_node = Node("5")
t.root.l_node.r_node.l_node = Node("8")
t.root.r_node = Node("3")
t.root.r_node.l_node = Node("6")
t.root.r_node.r_node = Node("7")
t.root.r_node.r_node.l_node = Node("9")
t.root.r_node.r_node.l_node.l_node = Node("11")
t.root.r_node.r_node.r_node = Node("10")
```

I created Stack() class to work with.
I tried to combine recursion and stack pushing but I'm out of ideas.

Queue implementation is very easy but it's important for me to have a Stack() implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithmically, a BFS is tied to queue operations and DFS is tied to stack operations.

If you only have stacks though, you can form something like a queue out of two stacks.

Stacks implement a FILO (first-in,last-out) order, whereas queues implement FIFO (first-in, first out).

If you put three numbers, 1,2,3 in a stack, and pull them out, you come up with 3,2,1.

If you did the same thing with a queue, they would come out as 1,2,3.

Now suppose we put 1,2,3 in stack A, pulled them out as 3,2,1, and put them in stack B. Taking them out of stack B would yield them as 1,2,3, which means that going through two stacks resembles going through  a queue.

Now this argument by itself works if you have the whole sequence and input everything all at once and then take it all out. But for BFS/DFSsearches this is not true, you input some things, then take them out before you input more.

You can still make a BFS work by only moving things from stack A to stack B if stack B is totally empty, and at that point transferring the entirety of stack A into B. B being empty ensures things that are put into stack B are all processed before the things being collected in stack A. Putting the entirety of A into B ensures all nodes at the same distance from the center node are kept in the same stack (either A or B) at any given time. Every transfer of content from stack A to B represents being done processing a BFS level at a particular distance from the start node, and inner layers are guaranteed to process before outer layers, which is what a BFS is.

```py
stack_a = Stack()
stack_b = Stack()

stack_b.Push(t.root)
while len(stack_a)+len(stack_b)>0:
    if len(stack_b) >0:
        current_node = stack_b.Pop()
    else:
        while len(stack_a)> 0:
            stack_b.Push(stack_a.Pop())
        current_node = stack_b.Pop()
    process(current_node) # this gets called on nodes in BFS order
    for neighbor in [current_node.l_node, current_node.r_node]:
        stack_a.Push(neighbor)
        #can generalize this to non-binary graphs by iterating through all unvisited neighbors
        #for cyclical graphs, must track processed nodes to ensure nodes don't get processed more than once
```